# _escaped_fragment_ не могу разобраться с htaccess для prerender.io

Tags: .htaccess, angularjs, seo, angular-ui-router

Проблема следующего характера, ссылки типа

http://mysite.com/anylink?_escaped_fragment_=

на prerender.io получаю кеш страниц без проблем ввиде

http://mysite.com/anylink

а запрос типа

http://mysite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=

prerender.io выдает

http://mysite.com/**index.html.var**

после чего я получаю отрендренную страницу 404, вместо главной,

а нужно получить http://mysite.com/

*Как исправить данную проблему?* Ниже пример кода

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "MyToken"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$  [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Prerender.io stuff
    <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_=

        # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
        RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [P,QSA,L]
    </IfModule>

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

angular:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode(true);
```

html

```
<base href="/">
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location) {
            $injector.invoke(['$state',
                function($state) {
                    if ($location.$$path == '/index.html.var')
                        $state.go('/'); // redirect to /
                    else
                        $state.go('404'); // else go to 404 state
                }
            ]);
        });
```